# Recover from the solution $y=\log (m \cos^{-1} x)$ the original equation $(1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}=ke^{-2y}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1}{m\cos^{-1} \big(x \sqrt{1-x^2}\big)}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1}{e^y\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

So
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{1}{e^{2y}(1-x^2)}\left(-\frac{e^yx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+e^y \sqrt{1-x^2} \frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$

I am not able to rearrange this into the required from. How should I proceed?

Comment: your question title isnt complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your $\frac{dy}{dx}$. In fact $m$ should not be in the denominator.
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{\cos^{-1}(x)\:\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{x}{\cos^{-1}(x)\:(1-x^2)^{3/2}}-\frac{1}{(\cos^{-1}(x))^2\:(1-x^2)}$$
Puting both into the ODE and after simplification :
$$-\frac{m^2+k}{m^2(\cos^{-1}(x))^2}=0$$
Thus in general $y=\log (m \cos^{-1} x)$ is not solution of the ODE. It is solution of the ODE only in the particular case $k=-m^2$.